# Jackson serialization and nexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property 'name'

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I am trying to write code that uses Jackson to serialize/deserialize the objects.

The objects are Polymorphic in nature:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "name")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = ComparableQuery.class),
    @Type(value = CompositeQuery.class)
})
public abstract class BaseQuery {

    private final Long characteristicId;

...
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "name")
public class CompositeQuery extends BaseQuery {

    private final String operator;
    private final BaseQuery[] queries;

    public CompositeQuery(Long characteristicId, Operator operator, BaseQuery... queries) {
        super(characteristicId);
        this.operator = operator.value;
        this.queries = queries;
    }

...
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "name")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = EqualQuery.class),
    @Type(value = GreaterOrEqualQuery.class),
    @Type(value = GreaterQuery.class),
    @Type(value = LessOrEqualQuery.class),
    @Type(value = LessQuery.class)
})
public abstract class ComparableQuery extends BaseQuery {

    private final Object value;

    private final String comparisonOperator;

...
}

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "name")
public class EqualQuery extends ComparableQuery {

    public EqualQuery(Long characteristicId, Object value) {
        super(characteristicId, value, "=");
    }

}
```

I have created a `Set<BaseQuery>` with a following code:

```
    Set<BaseQuery> queries = new HashSet<>();

    BaseQuery megapixelCharacteristicQuery = new CompositeQuery(megapixelCharacteristic.getCharacteristicId(), CompositeQuery.Operator.AND, new GreaterOrEqualQuery(megapixelCharacteristic.getCharacteristicId(), 10), new LessOrEqualQuery(megapixelCharacteristic.getCharacteristicId(), 50));
    queries.add(megapixelCharacteristicQuery);
```

Right now when I try to serialize the object I receive a following JSON:

```
[
   {
      "characteristicId":391,
      "operator":"AND",
      "queries":[
         {
            "name":"GreaterOrEqualQuery",
            "characteristicId":391,
            "value":10,
            "comparisonOperator":">="
         },
         {
            "name":"LessOrEqualQuery",
            "characteristicId":391,
            "value":50,
            "comparisonOperator":"<="
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

but when I try to deserialize the JSON document I'm receiving the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (END_OBJECT), expected FIELD_NAME: missing property 'name' that is to contain type id  (for class com.example.decision.query.characteristic.BaseQuery)
 at [Source: [{"characteristicId":391,"operator":"AND","queries":[{"name":"GreaterOrEqualQuery","characteristicId":391,"value":10,"comparisonOperator":">="},{"name":"LessOrEqualQuery","characteristicId":391,"value":50,"comparisonOperator":"<="}]}]; line: 1, column: 233] (through reference chain: java.util.HashSet[0])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:261)
```

For a some reason the `name` field is absent in the JSON root object.

How to fix it ?

**UPDATED**

It is working fine when I try to serialize only for example `megapixelCharacteristicQuery` object:

```
BaseQuery megapixelCharacteristicQuery = new CompositeQuery(megapixelCharacteristic.getCharacteristicId(), CompositeQuery.Operator.AND, new GreaterOrEqualQuery(megapixelCharacteristic.getCharacteristicId(), 10), new LessOrEqualQuery(megapixelCharacteristic.getCharacteristicId(), 50));
```

In this case Jackson forms the following JSON(with a correct `"name":"CompositeQuery"`):

```
{
   "name":"CompositeQuery",
   "characteristicId":391,
   "operator":"AND",
   "queries":[
      {
         "name":"GreaterOrEqualQuery",
         "characteristicId":391,
         "value":10,
         "operator":">="
      },
      {
         "name":"LessOrEqualQuery",
         "characteristicId":391,
         "value":50,
         "operator":"<="
      }
   ]
}
```

but serialization/deserialization still doesn't work when `megapixelCharacteristicQuery` is placed inside of `HashSet<BaseQuery>`.

How to make it work with HashSet ?

Also, it is start working fine even with a `HashSet` when I add `defaultImpl = CompositeQuery.class` to `JsonTypeInfo` annotation, for example:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "name", defaultImpl = CompositeQuery.class)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = ComparableQuery.class),
    @Type(value = CompositeQuery.class)
})
public abstract class BaseQuery {
...
}
```

but it is not an option to me because I don't know what type should be used in different cases so I'm still look for a solution how to correctly provide `name` parameter in my JSON.

Comment: did you check that name is set on the object your trying to serialize ?

Comment: As you can see from my question, the name field is only set on the nested objects

Comment: But for a some reason the name field is not set for `CompositeQuery` object and right now I don't understand why..

Comment: If it is not set on the Java object Jackson won't serialize that field in JSON.
Jackson will try to deserialize by defualt all attributes as mandatory unless marked with @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY) annotation, in which it won't through this exception.

Comment: `@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "name")` annotation  should automatically add one extra field `name` to the serialized object as it has been done for example for nested `GreaterOrEqualQuery` object(please see the JSON in my question).. but this property is absent for a some unknown reason for the his owner - `CompositeQuery`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, thanks to the answer provided in the following question [Why does Jackson polymorphic serialization not work in lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34193177/why-does-jackson-polymorphic-serialization-not-work-in-lists) I have found a solution:

```
Set<BaseQuery> queries = new HashSet<BaseQuery>() {
};
```

did the trick. Now everything works as expected.