# Jackson does not serialize subclass properly

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I am using Jackson to serialize Java objects for rest api. In Java I have an User class from which inherits Admin class.
If I request data from ReactJS through method that returns `Collection<User>` I get only `id` for Admin objects.

Here is my **User** class:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
@NamedQueries(
        @NamedQuery(name = "User.findByName",
            query = "SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.firstName = :firstName AND u.lastName = :lastName"))
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "user_type")
public class User extends AbstractEntity {

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(nullable = false, name = "first_name")
private String firstName;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(nullable = false, name = "last_name")
private String lastName;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
private String email;
...
```

Then I have **Admin** class:

```
@Entity
public class Admin extends User {
}
```

I expect to receive JSON objects in same form for Admin as for User, but Admin objects are serialized just with `id` and nothing else.

Does it require any additional configuration for Jackson?

I guess it has something incommon with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34193177/why-does-jackson-polymorphic-serialization-not-work-in-lists)

Comment: I don't see getters in your code. If fields do not have getters they will not be serialized.

Comment: Sorry, of course there are getters, setters and default constructors. I didn't want to share whole class, because it's quite long. However, I do not have getters/setters in Admin class, but methods of super class should be use in thah case.