# Difference in serialisation of Polymorphic Types to Json

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, fasterxml

I have a class where I've applied `@JsonTypeInfo` and `JsonSubTypes` as follows,

```
public class RequestDto {
    private List<IFoo> pageConfig = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

```
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = Id.NAME,
    include = As.PROPERTY,
    property = "iSlotType",
    visible = true
)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @Type(value = LSlot.class),
    @Type(value = WSlot.class)
})
public interface IFoo {
   ...
}
```

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@JsonTypeName("lSlot")
public class LSlot implements IFoo{
    private String id;
}
```

Interesting thing is that when I serialise an object of `RequestDto`, serialization is as expected,

```
{
    "pageConfig": [
        {
            "iSlotType": "lSlot",
            "id": "1001"
        },
        {
            "iSlotType": "wSlot",
            "id": "23",
            "parentId": "34"
        }
    ]
}
```

but when I serialize only the list as,

```
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestDto.getPageConfig);
```

I get the string without typeInfo IFoo types,

```
[
    {
        "id": "1001"
    },
    {
        "id": "23",
        "parentId": "34"
    }
]
```

How do I get the typeInfo here too ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34193177/why-does-jackson-polymorphic-serialization-not-work-in-lists

Comment: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34194367/13149219)